# Remove non-numerical values from multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio

I am a react developer flying solo on a project. I have a sprint item that requests that I remove non numeric values from one of our data columns. I am not really a SQL guy so I am not sure what I am doing and need a little guidance on the syntax for this.

```
APINumber
30-015-47040
123456789
3001546601
4230134963
30
```

this is a small sample of what the data looks like, but there are 623 rows total.

the goal is to remove all the dashes from all the rows and just leave the integers.

**Update**

Via the helpful comments below I was able to run a query and get rid of the dashes, however the change does not persist, when you query the table after, the changes come right back. Is there a way to commit a change via SQL?

After running replace Query:

[image]

Then Querying the table:
[image]

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for that? Just use `replace(APINumber,'-','')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question edit I think you have misunderstood the comments.

You appear to want to *update* the data:

```
update dbo.Well
  set APINumber = replace(APINumber,'-','')
where APINumber like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT replace(APINumber,'-','') FROM dbo.Well;

Comment: So I have run it and it works! Except its not persisting, when I query the table again the dashes come right back. Is there something I need to do in SQL to commit the change?

Comment: This is only for select values and if you want to reflect changes then you need to update a column with new values. Please use Stu comment code which will resolve your issue.